# Why my spinner onitemselected method doesn't initialize

Tags: java, android, firebase, spinner

I'm pulling the weekly data of students from firebase and adding an arraylist inside a class and I return this arraylist to Teacheractivity and I send this arraylist to spinner inside spinner class when i run emulator i can see data in spinner but when i click nothing happens. It doesn't give any error. I wrote it in separate classes to write clean code. Could this be a problem? I don't understand why this happened.

**My TeacherActivity**

```
    public class TeacherDersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityTeacherDersBinding binding;
    String lesson_name;
    ArrayList<String> WeekContentArraylist;
    _Spinner spinner;
    GetWeeks getWeeks;


    static void SpinnerList(_Spinner spinner)
    {
        spinner.init();
    }

    public void init() {


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        lesson_name= intent.getStringExtra("teacher_lesson");
        getWeeks = new GetWeeks(this);

        WeekContentArraylist = getWeeks.GetWeekContent(lesson_name);
        spinner = new _Spinner(TeacherDersActivity.this, WeekContentArraylist);
        SpinnerList(spinner);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityTeacherDersBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);
        init();



    }
}
```

---

GetWeeks class from which I pull data from Firebase

**My GetWeeks class**

```
    public class GetWeeks {
     FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;
    ArrayList<String> arrayListWeekContent;
    Activity _activity;


    public GetWeeks(Activity activity)
    {
        _activity = activity;
        mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        arrayListWeekContent = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void init()
    {

    }

    protected ArrayList<String> GetWeekContent(String lesson_name)
    {

        mFirestore.collection("Lessons")
                .document(lesson_name)
                .collection("Documents")
                .document("Docs1")
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(_activity, new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(@NonNull DocumentSnapshot documentsnapshots) {


                        arrayListWeekContent.add(documentsnapshots.getString("Week1"));
                        arrayListWeekContent.add(documentsnapshots.getString("Week2"));
                        arrayListWeekContent.add(documentsnapshots.getString("Week3"));
                        arrayListWeekContent.add(documentsnapshots.getString("Week4"));
                        arrayListWeekContent.add(documentsnapshots.getString("Week5"));
                        arrayListWeekContent.add(documentsnapshots.getString("meetLink"));


                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(_activity, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                System.out.println("GetWeeks FAIL");
            }
        });

        return arrayListWeekContent;
    }

}
```

---

**My Spinner class**

```
  public class _Spinner extends Activity  {

    Activity activityTeacherDers;

    ArrayList<String> WeekContentArraylist;

    public _Spinner(Activity activityTeacherDers, ArrayList<String> WeekContentArraylist)
    {
        this.activityTeacherDers = activityTeacherDers;
        this.WeekContentArraylist= WeekContentArraylist;
    }

    public void init()
    {

        Spinner spinner = activityTeacherDers.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activityTeacherDers,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,WeekContentArraylist);


        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                System.out.println("Heloooasdasdsa dataa ");  //<---- nothing happen hear
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });


    }

}
```

Comment: Is your `onItemSelected()` even triggered?

Comment: onitemselected not working or onNothingSelected